# What information is needed to estimate the Joint PDF of two rv?

Tags: estimation, multivariate-analysis, joint-distribution, copula

I've been reading multiple posts on the site about estimating Joint PDF and I understood why you can't estimate it from marginals. I also understand the use of Copulas. But curiously a lot of users had this answer: "you need more information in than just the marginals in order to estimate the joint PDF" but unfortunately without any further details.

What is the additional information needed on top of the marginals in order to estimate it? And how would that be done?

Comment: Consider a table representing the joint distribution, and, we only know row and column sums. How hard does it seem to fill up all the table values?

Comment: I understand your point. I was asking more about what are the needed pieces (that maybe I'm unaware of) to get the joint distribution in the first place

Answer (score 2):

The usual setting for estimating a joint pdf, is of having paired observations, say a sample of the form $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dotsc, (x_n,y_n)$. Then we can do business. If you have less than that, you should tell us more about your context, and why ...

There are many possibilities. If you know your two variables are independent, then the marginals are enough! If you somehow know the correlation, and the marginals, maybe maximum entropy can help. Otherwise, tell us!

---

As for additional question in comments: Very broad, tell us about your real application, maybe kernel density estimation, see [Best practices for density estimation of discrete & continuous random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12759/best-practices-for-density-estimation-of-discrete-continuous-random-variables)

Comment: This is interesting. So if we do have paired observations as you first said, what procedures can we follow to estimate the joint PDF?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The real application is basically finding the Joint Distribution of a financial instrument's returns (which are usually approximately normal) and one or multiple other variables (say the returns of another instrument or another non-normal variable).
I suppose it would be easy to collect a sample of paired observations from historical data as you pointed out in the initial setting, but I'd be glad to hear about multiple viable options that I can read up on (I'm more interested in learning the different methods than just solving this particular problem. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then ask a new question (linking back here) giving context and a lot of details!

Comment: That's all the information I have actually. I'm not sure what more I should provide? It's more of a theoretical question rather than a specific problem to be solved as I said I'm interested in learning the different methods that can be used.